# How to cast/convert a Struct to Protobuf?

Tags: go, struct, protocol-buffers, proto

I am working on a personal project & using Go for the first time. I am using structs for operating on the data and for storing the data in a file, I am using proto as the encoder.

In the project, my proto definition looks something like this

```
message Data {
    string key = 1;
    string value = 2;
}

message Record {
    int64 size = 1;
    Data data = 2;
}
```

and my struct looks like this

```
type KVData struct {
    Key       string
    Value     string
}
```

Currently, this is how I am creating proto data

```
kvData := KVData{Key: "name", Value: "A"}

record := &pb.Record{
        Size: 20,
        Data: &pb.Data{Key: "name", Value: "A"},
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to do this:

```
record := &pb.Record{
        Size: 20,
        Data: &((pb.Data)kvData), // Won't work
}

// or like Python

record := &pb.Record{
        Size: 20,
        Data: &(pb.Data{**kvData}), // Won't work
}
```

I tried googling but couldn't find any solution explaining how to do this.

Note, I am not just trying to solve this specific case, I also want to know what's the recommended Go way to operate between structs and proto(use only proto?)?

Comment: `kvData.(pb.Data)`

Comment: Getting this `invalid type assertion: kvData.(pb.Data) (non-interface type KVData on left)`

Comment: sorry got it mixed up, `pb.Data(kvData)`

Comment: Now, this is failing with `cannot convert kvData (type KVData) to type pb.Data`

Comment: FYI... the protobuf field numbers for message `Record` should probably be `1` and `2` - not `3` and `4`. Message `Record` is independent of message `Data` - so their field numbers are independent.  One would only need to start at a later number if you were sunsetting a field value for backward compatibility.

Comment: My bad, I removed some of the fields for the sake of brevity. Will fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot, at least not in Go 1.12.7.

Go's Protobuf compiler adds 3 extra fields to each struct generated from a message:

```
XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral         struct{} `json:"-"`
XXX_unrecognized             []byte   `json:"-"`
XXX_sizecache                int32    `json:"-"`
```

Therefore your `struct` and generated one have different fields and are not identical as per, therefore not [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability).

If two structs differ only in the tags, it is possible to [convert it](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Address *struct {
        Street string
        City   string
    }
}

var data *struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Address *struct {
        Street string `json:"street"`
        City   string `json:"city"`
    } `json:"address"`
}

var person = (*Person)(data)  // ignoring tags, the underlying types are identical
```

You have to create a new `struct` instance manually.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is something like:

```
pbData := pb.Data(kvData) // convert kvData struct to pb.Data struct

record := &pb.Record{
        Size: 20,
        Data: &pbData,
}
```

**Note:** you *cannot* combine these two steps like so:

```
record := &pb.Record{
    Size: 20,
    Data: &(pb.Data(kvData)), // BROKEN: can't get address of a return-value
}
```

You can experiment more here: https://play.golang.org/p/2AhWi0Khe4l

**EDIT:** pre [go 1.8](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8) struct types could not be converted if they were not exactly identical (same tags etc.) Updated playground link to demo mismatched tags will convert with `go 1.8` or later.

Comment: I think Pawel's answer is correct about proto. Proto adds a few extra fields. But your answer does touch some part of my question and it's helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! The question did not include the protoc version you were using.  Yes using `syntax = "proto3";` it would be cumbersome to include the extra generated `XXX` fields just for trivial type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gogofaster which is a third-party library to generate go code from your .proto files.

gogofaster is a faster generation tool and it does not include the extra fields (XXX_*) in structs making the conversion simpler (as the structs will now be identical).

You can learn more about it here : https://github.com/gogo/protobuf

Prototool by Uber also support gogofaster.

Hope this helps.